# Ajax - Update database on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need some help with a project. I'm still learning javascript and jquery so bear with me. The website that I'm working on needs to update a database entry when a button is clicked, the button content is also queried from the database.

First database query to get the buttons:

```
<?php
    $freq_sql = "SELECT freq FROM disc_freq WHERE in_use='0'";
    $result_freq = $connection->query($freq_sql);
    echo "<h5>Available frequencies</h5>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_freq)){
        $set_freq=$row[0];
?>
<a id='button' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><?php echo $set_freq ?></a>
```

Then the ajax script I tried but there is something wrong with it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "set_freq.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"set_freq":<?php echo $set_freq ?>}, 
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.toString(data);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Finally the php file

```
<?php
session_start();
include("konf.php");  
if(isSet($_POST['set_freq'])){ 
    $update_sql="UPDATE disc_freq SET in_use = '1', working_usr='".$_SESSION['username']."' WHERE freq='".$_POST['ins_freq']."'";
    $update_run=mysqli_query($connection,$update_sql);  
}  
?>
```

For some the first button when clicked on initiates same number ajax calls of how many buttons have been displayed. Others won't do anything.

The php code does work but the only problem is the ajax call and I haven't found a solution yet so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any error on console ?

Comment: what problems you are facing in you ajax call ?

Comment: No errors in console

Comment: It doesn't update the database when the button is clicked

Comment: success: function(data){
                data = JSON.toString(data);
console.log(data);
            } 
and check console for returned data

Comment: Troubleshoot your ajax call in browser network tab..and see what happens

Comment: Is there more than one link (#button) generated??

Comment: console.log returns [object JSON]

Comment: There are many links generated. It's based in database records.

Comment: @Michael than you should use class(.)  as selector.

Comment: i have tried that. It makes all the links to not work properly.

Comment: @Michael how can you try ? can update in your questions

Answer (score 1):

please update code as in your code there is error in ajax script in js 
change
  you can change code from

```
  data: {"set_freq":<?php echo $set_freq ?>},
```

to

```
   data: {"set_freq":'<?php echo $set_freq ?>'},
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should prevent your page to refresh because you are clicking on `a` tag so.

You should send your data with @pritamkumar's answer or also send like my answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(event){
       var data=$(this).text();
        event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            url: "set_freq.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"set_freq":data}, 
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.toString(data);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

As  per your comment that there are many links than you should change your selector. Like as below

```
<a class='button' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><?php echo $set_freq ?></a>
```

And also change JS code

```
$(".button").click(function(event)
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work with `<a>` links. Had to use `<button>` instead. Although pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is always  passed  the same  value to ajax

```
data: {"set_freq":<?php echo $set_freq ?>},
```

in html  change

```
  <a id='button' class='button w3-bar-item w3-button' data-freq='<?php echo 
    $set_freq ?>'><?php echo $set_freq ?></a>
```

in  js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "set_freq.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"set_freq":this.data('freq')}, 
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.toString(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

i didn't  test  it - writing  from "memory"